# String diagrams when you have two monoidal products

Tags: category-theory

Sometimes it's useful to define more than one monoidal product on the same category. A good example is $\textbf{Set}$, where you have the product and the coproduct.

If we choose one or the other of those, we can use string diagrams, which are very useful. For $\textbf{Set}$ we can choose the product, in which case parallel boxes on parallel wires represent two functions being evaluated simultaneously on different arguments, or we can choose the coproduct, in which case the same diagram represents either one function being evaluated or the other.

However, sometimes it seems like it would be useful to be able to represent both monoidal operations at once somehow, for example, in a computational context in which we might have both branching and parallel execution.

Does there exist a diagrammatic calculus, similar to string diagrams, that would be suitable in such a case?

(I've kept the question deliberately vague, because I don't know what such a diagram might look like, or what additional axioms would have to be obeyed to make it work.)

Comment: Yeah There are some suggestions here, but as far as I can tell the answer to a strong interpretation of your question is no: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283574/string-diagrams-for-bimonoidal-categories-a-k-a-rig-categories Baez has conjectured that the initial such category is finite sets, which is already much more complicated than the free monoidal category *on an object*, which would go some way to explain the challenge here.

Comment: Oops, the initial such category is proposed to be the *groupoid* of finite sets, which is equivalent to the free monoidal category on an object-this still implies that the free bimonoidal category on an object is rather more complex than in the monoidal case.

Comment: @KevinCarlson thanks, that's a very useful link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comfort–Delpeuch–Hedges introduced *sheet diagrams* for [rig categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig+category), i.e. categories with two monoidal structures, one of which distributes over the other, in [Sheet diagrams for bimonoidal categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.13361) (2020), for which $(\mathbf{Set}, {\times}, {+})$ is a prototypical example.

Comment: The question was partly inspired by some lectures that Jules Hedges gave around 2019, so it's maybe not surprising that his paper gives an answer!

Comment: Oh, I see! I thought it was likely you knew of this paper, but thought it was useful to provide an answer anyway for anyone else who might come across this question :)